# how to get serial number via win32 wpd api

Tags: winapi, wpd

as shown in title, i search on google for this question, but there seems that no way get serial number via WPD(Windows Portable Device) api, and in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff597865(v=vs.85).aspx), i found the WPD_DEVICE_SERIAL_NUMBER property of Portable Device, can anyone tell me how to get this property using wpd api?

Answer (score 0):

The C++ sample can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd389002(v=vs.85).aspx) and [here](https://github.com/pauldotknopf/WindowsSDK7-Samples/tree/master/multimedia/wpd/WpdServicesApiSample/cpp)

Comment: i founded that.  using the following api:  [IPortableDeviceContent::Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388540(v=vs.85).aspx)
  [IPortableDeviceProperties::GetValues](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388714(v=vs.85).aspx)  and [IPortableDeviceValues::GetStringValue(WPD_DEVICE_SERIAL_NUMBER, &sn)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375661(v=vs.85).aspx)  can get the serial number

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a process.  Basic steps are as follows:

1. Get and populate a `IPortableDeviceValues` of your client info

```
    // Create our client information collection
    ThrowIfFailed(CoCreateInstance(
        CLSID_PortableDeviceValues,
        nullptr,
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        IID_PPV_ARGS(&clientInfo)));

    // We have to provide at the least our name, version, revision
    ThrowIfFailed(clientInfo->SetStringValue(
        WPD_CLIENT_NAME,
        L"My super cool WPD client"));

    ThrowIfFailed(clientInfo->SetUnsignedIntegerValue(
        WPD_CLIENT_MAJOR_VERSION,
        1));

    ThrowIfFailed(clientInfo->SetUnsignedIntegerValue(
        WPD_CLIENT_MINOR_VERSION,
        0));

    ThrowIfFailed(clientInfo->SetUnsignedIntegerValue(
        WPD_CLIENT_REVISION,
        1));
```

2. Get an `IPortableDevice` with `CoCreateInstance`

```
    // A WPD device is represented by an IPortableDevice instance
    ThrowIfFailed(CoCreateInstance(
        CLSID_PortableDevice,
        nullptr,
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        IID_PPV_ARGS(&device)));
```

3. Connect to the device using `IPortableDevice::Open`, passing the device's ID and the above client info

```
    device->Open(deviceId.c_str(), clientInfo);
```

4. Get the device's `IPortableDeviceContent` using `IPortableDevice::Content`

```
    CComPtr<IPortableDeviceContent> retVal;

    ThrowIfFailedWithMessage(
        device.Content(&retVal),
        L"! Failed to get IPortableDeviceContent from IPortableDevice");
```

5. Get the content's `IPortableDeviceProperties` using `IPortableDeviceContent::Properties`

```
    CComPtr<IPortableDeviceProperties> retVal;

    ThrowIfFailedWithMessage(
        content.Properties(&retVal),
        L"! Failed to get IPortableDeviceProperties from IPortableDeviceContent");
```

6. Get the properties' `IPortableDeviceValues` using `IPortableDeviceProperties::GetValues`, passing `"DEVICE"` for `pszObjectID` and `nullptr` for `pKeys`

```
    CComPtr<IPortableDeviceValues> retVal;

    ThrowIfFailedWithMessage(
        properties.GetValues(objectId.c_str(), nullptr, &retVal),
        L"! Failed to get IPortableDeviceValues from IPortableDeviceProperties");
```

7. Get the serial number from the values using `IPortableDeviceValues::GetStringValue`, passing `WPD_DEVICE_SERIAL_NUMBER` for `key`

```
    propertyKey = WPD_DEVICE_SERIAL_NUMBER;

    LPWSTR value = nullptr;
    ThrowIfFailedWithMessage(
        values.GetStringValue(propertyKey, &value),
        L"! Failed to get string value from IPortableDeviceValues");

    propertyValue = value;
    if (value != nullptr)
    {
        CoTaskMemFree(value);
    }
```

By no means a complete listing, sorry.  The `ThrowIf*` functions are just basic helpers I wrote to go from checking `HRESULT`s to throwing exceptions.  Hopefully this points you in the right direction.

Additional references:

- [The dimeby8 blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dimeby8/enumerating-wpd-devices-part-1)
- [WPD Application Programming Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wpd_sdk/wpd-application-programming-interface)